# Showing Menu on XIB file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmenu, nswindowcontroller

i have 2 XIB file

1. the standard Main Menu file which has a menu
2. i added another XIB file to the project with a Window
   i added a Menu to the XIB file

i show the XIB file windows with following code

```
myController = [[NSWIndowController alloc]initWIthNibName......]];
[window showWindow];
```

my question : how do i connect the menu to the XIB/Window to display it.

1. how do i make the window Modal.

Comment: So now you have 2 xib and 2 menu? and you want to show only one menu all the time?

Comment: yes, i have 2 xib files and each of them has a menu